# Shortened codes into fewer line in returning xml reponse from database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Here is my code. Please help me to shortened this code into fewer lines. Data are fetched from database and added to the XML response.

```
header ("content-type: application/xml");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<config/>');
$xml_display = $xml->addChild('nas_sharing');
$count = $xml_display->addChild('auth_state', "1");
$count = $xml_display->addChild('count', count($videos));
        foreach($videos as $video){
            $fileName = str_replace(" ", "", basename($video['file_path']));
            $xml_item = $xml_display->addChild('item');
            $xml_item->addChild('favorite', $video["album_id"]);
            $xml_item->addChild('file_id', $video["file_id"]);
            $xml_item->addChild('file_name', base64_encode($video["file_name"]));
            $xml_item->addChild('file_ext', $video["file_ext"]);
            $xml_item->addChild('media_type', $video["media_type"]);
            $xml_item->addChild('file_size', $video["file_size"]);
            $xml_item->addChild('file_ctime', $video["file_ctime"]);
            $xml_item->addChild('file_owner', $video["file_owner"]);
            $xml_item->addChild('comment', $video["comment"]);
            $xml_item->addChild('inode', $video["inode"]);
            $xml_item->addChild('file_path', base64_encode($video["file_path"]));
            $xml_item->addChild('file_parsed', $video["file_parsed"]);
            $xml_item->addChild('file_thumbed', $video["file_thumbed"]);
            $xml_item->addChild('ctime_datetime', $video["ctime_datetime"]);
            //$xml_item->addChild('album_file_id', $video["album_file_id"]);
            //$xml_item->addChild('album_id', $video["album_id"]);
            $xml_item->addChild('thumb_path', base64_encode(dirname($video['file_path']).'/.thumbnail/'.$fileName.'.jpg'));

        }

         if (count($videos) > 0) {
        header ("content-type: application/xml");
        $xml_stat = new SimpleXMLElement('<myvideo/>');
        $xml_display = $xml_stat->addChild('status', "ok");

        } else {
        header ("content-type: application/xml");
        //$app->response->setStatus(200);
        $xml_stat = new SimpleXMLElement('<myvideo/>');
        $xml_display = $xml_stat->addChild('status', "not found");

        } 

        echo $xml_stat->asXml();
         $xml->asXml('../xml/myvideo_search_allvideo_'.$user.'.xml');


} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace (almost) all lines like

```
$xml_item->addChild('file_id', $video["file_id"]);
```

with a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construction:

```
foreach($video as $key => $value) {
    $xml_item->addChild($key, $value);
}
```

There are a few special cases you need to take care of, like renaming:

```
$xml_item->addChild('favorite', $video["album_id"]);
```

and conversion:

```
$xml_item->addChild('file_path', base64_encode($video["file_path"]));
```

Comment: It's work fine but how to remove and add conversion or renaming it inside a foreach loop? `foreach($video as $key => $value) {
    $xml_item->addChild($key, $value);
    //here..
}`

Comment: The simplest way would be `if ($key == 'album_id') { ... } else if ($key == 'file_path') { ... } else { $xml_item->addChild($key, $value); }`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Really big help.